# Is it grammatically correct to have full sentences in a list?

Tags: grammar, lists

Example:

> Her eyes were puffy, her lips were cracked, and her hair was a mess.

It is grammatically correct to put full sentences (independent clauses) in a list separated by commas? (Maybe they are not considered comma splices because they are in a list?)

Comment: On the first phrase, I thin you meant ‘and her hair was a mess’?

Comment: Also, I think you meant "considered NOT comma splices because they are in a list"?

Comment: @Buzzyy Thanks, I made the corrections.

Comment: @stangdon Thansk, I corrected that.

Comment: Yes, this: Her eyes were puffy, her lips were cracked, and her hair was a mess. is fine. Also: Her eyes were puffy, her lips cracked, and her hair, a mess. But that is not a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is absolutely OK in English grammar to write what could be complete sentences as clauses joined with conjunctions. You might get into a debate about punctuation (comma always between each clause?), but I don't think anyone would insist that words need to be formed into the shortest possible sentences.

*I am an American and I am over 50 years old.*

Those are two complete clauses that could be separate sentences. They do not have to be separate sentences.

Here is just one academic site that discusses this with examples:
https://www.kent.edu/writingcommons/using-commas-combine-sentences

Answer (score 1):

> Her eyes were puffy, her lips were cracked, and her [hair] was a mess.

I have inserted **hair** which I think you have missed out.

Edit

Your example is fine.
We could also consider using semicolons to separate the items.

According to [this site](https://www.iwu.edu/writing-center/student-resources/serial-sentences.html), the punctuation rule for series made of independent clauses is as follows:

> Punctuate the in-sentence list items with commas if they are not complete sentences; with semicolons, if they are complete sentences.

We could hence say

> Her eyes were puffy; her lips were cracked; and her [hair] was a mess.

Comment: I see no reason for you punctuation.

Comment: That document seems to be a style guide for a particular instituition, not a grammar of written English.

Comment: Thanks, @Lambie.  I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Colin Fine.  I have edited my answer.